# Problems attaching a file to an email intent in Android

Tags: android, xml, email, android-intent, mime-types

I know this question has been asked in several variations before, but my question revolves more around the setType method.

I am trying to attach an XML file to an email that I am starting with an Intent. The code is:

```
File exportPath = (File) data.getExtras().getSerializable("Path");
Log.w(TAG, Uri.fromFile(exportPath).toString());
Intent email = new Intent();
email.setType("application/xml");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {user_email});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(exportPath));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Mail job"));
```

The recipient, subject, and text come in correctly, only the attachment is missing.

The result of:
    Log.w(TAG, Uri.fromFile(exportPath).toString()); 
is file:///mnt/sdcard/SDS2Mobile/model2.xml

I think my problem is that I am setting the type incorrectly, but I am unable to find the correct type for XML files. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I was trying to email an sqlite db file and was having the hardest time.  Your part of the code "Uri.fromFile(exportPath)" is what fixed it for me. Thanks a million!

Comment: You have to create your intent with a send command otherwise I could not get it to work. `Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! using "text/Message" in setType() produced the correct results.